# Updating a UITable inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath causes leak in iOS7, but not iOS6

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios7

I have a UITableView that I modify (delete one row and insert one row) when the user clicks on any of the rows.  Memory deallocation works great in iOS6 and earlier, but iOS7 will not release the tableview.  Here is the basics of my code.  I have reduced the code hugely, but the issue is still there.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)intableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [intableView beginUpdates];
    [intableView endUpdates];
}
```

The begin/end updates cause the memory to get held somewhere.  It's the same if I insert or delete rows (along with the background data array) inside this function.  I subclassed the UITableView and cells with just adding:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"deallocated %@",[self class]);
}
```

So that I can see when they get deallocated.  Are we not supposed to update the tableview on selection anymore?  Is it in a different thread where something gets held? (I have tried `dispatch_async` into different threads)

I could post more code, but my current code looks just like what I posted and it is still holding on to the tableview somehow and not deallocating it.

Comment: Sounds like an Apple bug. Please file a but in https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: And if you comment out ```[intableView beginUpdates];
    [intableView endUpdates];``` does the behavior go away?

Comment: Yes.  The table gets deallocated when the begin and end updates are not called.  I can even reload the table data and the table gets released properly, but then the animation of removing and adding the cells is gone.

Comment: You can find my solution here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19008101/2814997