# iOS7 UITableView memory leak

Tags: uitableview, ios7, memory-leaks

I have a UITableView that has expanding sections.  When the user first loads the table view, the parent record for each section is loaded.  When the user presses on the parent cell, i retrieve the child data from the database and then insert the new cells into the table view using

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:expandCollapseArr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

Then, if the user clicks the parent cell again, the child cells, are removed using

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:expandCollapseArr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

The above code is working as expected.  The problem is that on iOS 7, using ARC, the inserted and deleted cells are never removed from memory, even after destorying the UitableView and the UIViewController itself.  After using the app forawhile, a memory warning will be thrown and the app will crash.

If I take out the insertRowsAtIndexPaths and deleteRowsAtIndexPaths calls, and just call `[tableView reloadData]` each time, everything works fine and all memory is releashed when I'm done with the view controller, but then i loose the inserting and deleting animations.

There seems to be a native memory leak involved when using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Here the reuse identifier code i am using ...

```
NSString *searchStr = @"Store ";
NSRange match = [displayString rangeOfString: searchStr];
if (match.location == NSNotFound) {
        CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%@%@", displayString, TBL_NAME];
} else {
        CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Store%@", TBL_NAME];
}

ExpandableTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
if (cell == nil ) { 
    cell = [[ExpandableTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; }
```

Comment: Can't you do the insertRowsAtIndexPaths: and deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: and only after that animation is done do a reloadData?

Comment: Are you dequeueing cells? If you are, the table view should only ever instantiate enough cells to fill the screen. Please show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and any custom cell code.

Comment: Also, you can try running the "Outline" example project in [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com). It does what you're describing and I expanded/collapsed it for several minutes and didn't see any memory growth.

Comment: Totumus - I've tried that and the memory from the inserted cells still does not release.

Comment: Timothy - Each parent has it's own cell, so if there are 60 parent rows, there are 60 unique cells for the parents, but each child cell uses the same reuse identifier.  I tried using the same reuse identifier for every cell and still get the same result when inserting new cells

Comment: @jvencl Can you show some code? I double checked the example project I linked to above and the cells are indeed being exactly as expected. So it may be related to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or any custom cell classes.

Comment: NSString *searchStr = @"Store ";
        NSRange match = [displayString rangeOfString: searchStr];
        if (match.location == NSNotFound) {
            CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%@%@", displayString, TBL_NAME];
        } else {
            CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Store%@", TBL_NAME];
        }

Comment: ExpandableTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil ) {
            //NSLog(@"CREATING NEW CELL - %@", CellIdentifier);
            cell = [[ExpandableTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

Comment: Thats really hard to read. I would be much more useful if you could append the code to your question and show the entire method definition for context. Also, why are you using multiple cell identifiers when you only have one type of cell?

Comment: The parent cell is holding an identifier to tell if it is expanded or not.  Either way, even if i use the same identifier for all the cells, the memory problem is the same.

Comment: It looks to be an Apple bug.  I saw it with a simple beginUpdates followed by endUpdates, with nothing in between.  Disabling animations around the calls avoided the problem.  It seems the completion block of the internal animation never goes away if it's copied to a heap block, which retains the UITableView itself, meaning it along with all its cached cells don't go away.  Also posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919870/ios-7-0-and-arc-uitableview-never-deallocated-after-rows-animation

Comment: That's what I've read so far, that it is in fact an Apple bug, but does anyone know of a way to do the table insert and delete animation without causing a memory leak?  I can get my program to work just fine by using reloadData, but the animation gives the user a nice visual key that something has happened.

Comment: The solution on the linked question does basically work; that approach (or a refined version) is probably the only way to fix it outside of Apple doing it in an iOS update.  That solution does involve swizzling a core UIView method, but is pretty safe.  It basically wraps the completion block with a very small one, and ensures the real completion block gets dealloced properly.  The small wrapper block will still leak until Apple fixes the bug, but that's a much smaller problem.  I do hope to post an alternate solution soon, but it will be based on the same approach.

Comment: @CarlLindberg You're absolutely right! The wrapper block still leaking, but it can solve more-more serious problems. I'm curiously waiting for your alternate solution :)

Comment: @gabbayabb I did post my findings at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19330091/1754225 .

Comment: Good news! Apple appears to have fixed this bug as of iOS 7.0.3 (released today). See more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19530110/796419