# Basic advice on memory leaks in custom tableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-leaks

I'm really struggling to understand memory leaks from a custom tableViewCell in an ARC-based project and was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on if the following might be responsible or if I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely.

So, I'm pushing a tableViewController into a navigationController and in the tableView I have my own custom tableViewCells.

This custom tableViewCell has a *delegate* property which is assigned from cellForRowAtIndexPath and points to the tableViewController itself, so in other words...

```
cell.delegate = self;
```

This custom tableViewCell also has a couple of observers for NotificationCenter.

Now, I've put in code to remove the observers in the tableViewCell dealloc and likewise went to add...

```
self.delegate = Nil;
```

...only to discover dealloc doesn't ever seem to be called, even when going tapping Back (i.e. going back up the navigation stack effectively finishing with the pushed tableViewContoller).

So, I guess this boils down to: could either of these aspects of the cell cause a leak? And if so, am I going about stopping the leaks in the right way?

EDIT: I'm defining my delegate property as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyTableViewController *delegate;
```

Comment: Une instruments to find out what you're leaking (or over retaining) and where from. Is the delegate retained (generally shouldn't be). The table view controller should remove itself when the table view tells it the cell is no longer displayed.

Comment: It might help to see how you're defining your delegate iVar in your custom cell view.  However, know that `UITableViewCell` can be recycled (via `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`) for performance reasons.  If a table cell is reusable, you may not see an immediate dealloc on the object until the table view goes away.

Comment: Good point- have added my iVar definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your custom delegate as `weak`

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyCustomDelegateProtocol> delegate;
```

Otherwise you get a strong reference cycle

```
controller -> table view -> cell -> controller
```

n.b. `weak` is specific to ARC, if you're not using ARC you need to use `assign`, and make sure to nil it out yourself when you're done being its delegate.

Comment: That's a fair suggestion, especially given I'm using retain presently. Will give this a try and see if anything improves- cheers.

Comment: Great stuff- that's made a pretty sizeable improvement on the size of the leak, plus dealloc is now being called. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Another issue can be this one:

[iOS 7.0 and ARC: UITableView never deallocated after rows animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919870/ios-7-0-and-arc-uitableview-never-deallocated-after-rows-animation)

Not applicable if you're running on iOS 7.0.3+.

Comment: Yep- not applicable in this case but definitely good to know.