# Retain Cycle on Retain Cycles

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, retain-cycle

I'm seeing a gradual build up of memory that I think might be a retain cycle.

**When does this happen:** Click on a custom cell that expands and injects a nib with 3 buttons into the expanded area. Clicking the cell again closes the cell, shrinks the cell's tablerow height, rotates an open indicator and removes the previously injected nib.

If I open and close the cell multiple times I see the memory gradually building up.

Any ideas what might be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post photos.

Build up:
[image: http://imgur.com/Up6iAPr]

Example of retained objects(mostly Animation related): 
[image: http://imgur.com/8X2Tr8L]

EDIT: Using ARC and on iOS 6

### MasterViewController - TableView Functions

```
#pragma mark - UITABLEVIEW
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.topicsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"SRCollapsibleCellClosed";
    SRCollapsibleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SRCollapsibleCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
    }

    SRTopic *topic = [self.topicsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell updateWithTopic:topic];

    if([self isCellOpen:indexPath]){
        CGAffineTransform transformation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
        cell.arrow.transform = transformation;
        if(![self hasChoiceBox:cell]){
            [self insertChoiceBox:cell atIndex:indexPath];
        }
    } else{
        CGAffineTransform transformation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        cell.arrow.transform = transformation;
    }

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if([self isCellOpen:indexPath]){
        [self closeCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else{
        NSIndexPath * openCell= self.openCellIndex;
        NSIndexPath * newOpenCell= indexPath;
        [self closeCellAtIndexPath:openCell];
        [self openCellAtIndexPath:newOpenCell];
    }
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath {

    if([indexPath isEqual:self.openCellIndex]){
        return 217.0;
    } else {
        return 63.0;
    }
}

-(void)rotateCellArrowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath willOpen:(bool)willOpen Animated:(bool)animated{
    // Change Arrow orientation
    SRCollapsibleCell *cell = (SRCollapsibleCell*) [self.topicsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGAffineTransform transformation;

    if(willOpen){
        transformation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    } else {
        transformation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    }

    if(animated){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 delay:0 options:nil animations:^{
            cell.arrow.transform = transformation;
         }  completion:nil];
    }
    else{
        cell.arrow.transform = transformation;
    }
}



-(BOOL)isCellOpen:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return [indexPath isEqual:self.openCellIndex];
}

-(void)closeCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    //NSLog(@"Cell closing");
    [self rotateCellArrowAtIndexPath:indexPath willOpen:NO Animated:YES];
    [self removeSRChoiceBoxFromCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.openCellIndex = nil;
}

-(void)openCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    [self rotateCellArrowAtIndexPath:indexPath willOpen:YES Animated:YES];
    SRCollapsibleCell *cell = (SRCollapsibleCell*)[self.topicsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self insertChoiceBox:cell atIndex:indexPath];
    self.openCellIndex = indexPath;
}

-(void)removeSRChoiceBoxFromCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    SRCollapsibleCell *cell = (SRCollapsibleCell*) [self.topicsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    for(id subview in cell.SRCollapsibleCellContent.subviews){
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[SRChoiceBox class]]){
            SRChoiceBox *tempBox = subview;          
            [tempBox removeFromSuperview];
            tempBox.delegate = nil;
            tempBox = nil;
        }
    }
}

-(void)insertChoiceBox: (SRCollapsibleCell *)cell atIndex:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    //SRChoiceBox *newBox = [[SRChoiceBox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 141)];

    SRChoiceBox *newBox = [[SRChoiceBox alloc] init];    
    SRTopic *topic = [self.topicsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [newBox updateWithSRTopic:topic];
    newBox.delegate = self;

    [cell.SRCollapsibleCellContent addSubview:newBox];
    cell = nil;
    topic = nil;
    newBox = nil;
}

-(bool)hasChoiceBox:(SRCollapsibleCell *)cell{
    for(UIView *subview in cell.SRCollapsibleCellContent.subviews){
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[SRChoiceBox class]]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

### SRChoiceBox - UIView object that gets inserted into cell

```
//.h



@protocol SRChoiceBoxDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)positionWasChoosen: (NSString *)choice topicId: (NSNumber *)topicId;
@end

@interface SRChoiceBox : UIView
-(id) initWithLabel: (NSDictionary *)labels andTopicID: (NSNumber *)topicId andFrame:(CGRect)frame;



@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *SRChoiceBox;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *SRTopicId;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SRChoiceBoxDelegate> delegate;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *agreeCount;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *disagreeCount;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *observeCount;

-(IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender;
-(void)updateWithSRTopic:(SRTopic *)topic;

....
//.m

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SRChoiceBox" bundle:nil];
        NSArray *q = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:q[0]];
    }
    return self;

}

-(void)updateWithSRTopic:(SRTopic *)topic
{
    self.SRTopicId = topic.topicId;
    self.agreeCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",topic.agreeDebaters];
    self.disagreeCount.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",topic.disagreeDebaters];
    self.observeCount.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",topic.observers];
}



- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id) sender {

    int tag = [sender tag];
    switch (tag) {
        case 0:
            [self.delegate  positionWasChoosen:@"agree" topicId:self.SRTopicId];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self.delegate positionWasChoosen: @"disagree" topicId:self.SRTopicId];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self.delegate positionWasChoosen: @"observe" topicId:self.SRTopicId];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.SRChoiceBox =nil;
    self.SRTopicId=nil;
    self.delegate=nil;
    self.agreeCount=nil;
    self.disagreeCount=nil;
    self.observeCount=nil;
    //NSLog(@"choicebox deallocated: %@", self);
}
```

### SRCollapsibleCell -- Reusable cell

//.h

```
@interface SRCollapsibleCell : UITableViewCell


@property (strong) NSNumber *topicId;
@property (strong) NSDictionary *topicStats;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *subtitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *agreeDebaters;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *disagreeDebaters;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *observers;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *arrow;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *SRCollapsibleCellContent;

//-(void)updateWithTopic:(NSDictionary *) stats;
-(void)formatTitle:(NSString *)title;
-(void)updateWithTopic: (SRTopic *)topic;
@end
```

//.m

```
@implementation SRCollapsibleCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}




-(void)formatTitle:(NSString *)title{

    if(title.length<30){
        self.title.text= title;
        self.subtitle.text =@"";
    } else {
        NSArray *splitString = [self splitString:title maxCharacters:30];
        self.title.text = splitString[0];
        self.subtitle.text = splitString[1];
        splitString = nil;
        title = nil;
    }

}

////http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1197
- (NSArray *)splitString:(NSString*)str maxCharacters:(NSInteger)maxLength {
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    NSArray *wordArray = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSInteger numberOfWords = [wordArray count];
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSInteger lengthOfNextWord = 0;

    while (index < numberOfWords && tempArray.count<2) {
        NSMutableString *line = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:1];
        while ((([line length] + lengthOfNextWord + 1) <= maxLength) && (index < numberOfWords)) {
            lengthOfNextWord = [[wordArray objectAtIndex:index] length];
            [line appendString:[wordArray objectAtIndex:index]];
            index++;
            if (index < numberOfWords) {
                [line appendString:@" "];
            }
        }
        [tempArray addObject:line];

        NSMutableString *subtitle = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:1];

        while(index<numberOfWords){
            [subtitle appendString:[wordArray objectAtIndex:index]];
            [subtitle appendString:@" "];
            index++;
        }


        [tempArray addObject:subtitle];
        break;
    }
    return tempArray;
}


//Breaks MVC but it makes the MasterVC cleaner 
-(void)updateWithTopic: (SRTopic *)topic
{

    [self formatTitle:topic.title];
    self.topicId = topic.topicId;
    self.agreeDebaters.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",topic.agreeDebaters];
    self.disagreeDebaters.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", topic.disagreeDebaters];
    self.observers.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", topic.observers];

}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

@end
```

Comment: This nib that gets injected - does it have its own class? If so how about putting a log message in the dealloc ?

Comment: It does! In fact, there is a commented out NSLog statement in the bottom of the dealloc. (See: SRChoiceBox) The confusing part is that the nib gets deallocated just fine.

Comment: A silly suggestion, but I would start commenting out lines of code to try to narrow down your search for the issue.

Comment: @bluths_bananas Are you using ARC?

Comment: @luisChen Yes, I am using arc.

Comment: @pedro.m That's a good suggestion and something I've done. It seems to stem the animation of the table view height.  `[tableView endUpdates]` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. But I can't see why that would be or if that is in fact the root of the problem.

Comment: @bluths_bananas Looks like this might be the root of your problem indeed. Please check these [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903234/updating-a-uitable-inside-didselectrowatindexpath-causes-leak-in-ios7-but-not-i) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919870/ios-7-0-and-arc-uitableview-never-deallocated-after-rows-animation/19008101#19008101) for potential solutions.

Comment: Thanks again pedro. I saw those as well, but I forgot to mention this is happening in ios 6, xcode 4.6. Sorry, I should have mentioned that :)